# calling an abstract method from the subclass object

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

Here is my question. I have a super class with an abstract method in it.

```
public abstract class Base{

 public abstract Boolean foo();

}
public class sub extends Base{
 @Override
 public Boolean foo(){
   System.out.printLn("This is foo in the sub class!");
 }
}
```

so When I go to the main and try this code

```
Base b = new sub();
b.foo();
```

I got no error and message shows on my screen. My assumption is the compiler looks at the b object and sees it as a Base object then it goes to the foo from the Base object and sees there is no implementation afterwards it checks out the foo from the child and then it sees the method foo is implemented there so it shows the message. Am I right?

Comment: While you compile a Base, the runtime object is a sub. Method get called on runtime object.

Comment: Refer to [Abstract Classes documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/87/inheritance/397/abstract-classes#t=20160916155332004042).

Comment: Thank you guys , so the runtime object method foo is called rather than the base class method foo and therefore compiler does not complain about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler does not see if the method is implemented by subclass or not. It only checks whether method called by the a particular class type reference is present in the class itself or not. At runtime it decides which method to call means Base class version or Subclass version.

So you are only right upto "My assumption is the compiler looks at the b object and sees it as a Base object then it goes to the foo from the Base" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler does not do so much of processing. Here in your case 
You have created the reference variable as of your superclass which will hold the object of child class.

Now when you are calling the method it is directly calling the method present in your subclass based on your object type.

I am adding you code with my comments for your reference.

**1) Abstract class having only method declaration**

`public abstract class Base {
    public abstract Boolean foo(); //method declaration 
}`

**2) Child class extending your parent class where you have to implement the method,If you are declaring this class as concrete class.**

`public class sub extends Base {
    @Override
    public Boolean foo() {
        System.out.printLn("This is foo in the sub class!");
    }
}`

**3) Here you have declared reference variable of your parent type that is storing the object of you child class**

`Base b = new sub();`

**4) when this line will get executed compiler will check, what is the type of object and call that method on the basis of object type.It will not invoke methods on the type of reference variable.**

`b.foo();`